# Assembly 8086 overwrites text

Tags: assembly, input, output, x86-16, emu8086

I have this code were I need to insert text, and print it backwards, but when I print the text backwards, it overwrites a string I previously printed. Adding an image for a better understanding:

[I can solve it, by adding a line before the printBackWards method. but I'd like to know why this happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Ftv.png)

Thanks for your time.

```
;;deber#1-assembler RODRIGO MAIDANA
.model small
.stack 100h
.data   
    ;arreglo para colectar caracteres
    array db 256 dup('$'),'$'
    
    
    ;;Cadena de texto para solicitar valores y retornar valores
    msg db 10,13,7, "Ingrese un texto: $"
    resultado db 10,13,7, "El texto al reves es: $"
    
    msgERROR db 10,13,7, "VALOR INGRESADO NO ES CORRECTO$"  
    
.code
    

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    mov dx, offset msg
    call puts
    
    call readText
    
    mov cx, si
    dec si
    
    call putLine
    
    mov dx, offset resultado
    call puts
    
    ;;call putLine
    
    call printArrayBackwards
    
     
    call finish
    
    
    ;;Usamos contador para recorrer el array
    printArrayBackwards:
         mov dl, array[si]
         dec si
         call putc
         
         loop printArrayBackwards 
         ret
    
    ;;Lee el texto que ingresa el usuario hasta ingresar Enter(13) o Esc(27).
    readText:
        call getc               ;;Pedimos caracteres
        
        mov array[si],al        ;;Agregamos caracter al array
        inc si
        
        cmp al,13               ;;Verificamos si el caracter ingreado es ENTER 
        jne verifyEsc           ;;Si no es Enter(13) vamos a verifyEsc
        ret   
    
        verifyEsc: 
            cmp al,27           ;;Verificamos si el caracter ingreado es ESCAPE
            jne readText        ;;Si no es Esc(27) ejecutamos de vuelta la sub-rutina
            
            dec si
            mov array[si],0h    ;;Borramos tecla esc
            inc si
            ret
   
    ;;Agrega un salto de linea
    putLine:
        push ax
        push bx
        push cx
        push dx
        
        mov dl, 13d
        call putc
        
        mov dl, 10d
        call putc
        
        pop dx
        pop cx
        pop bx
        pop ax
        ret  
    
    ;;Ingresa chart por teclado
    getc:
        push bx
        push cx
        push dx 
        
        mov ah, 1h
        int 21h
        
        pop dx
        pop cx
        pop bx
        ret
    
    ;;Imprimimos un caracter   
    putc:     
        push ax
        push bx
        push cx
        push dx  
        
        mov ah, 2h
        int 21h  
        
        pop dx
        pop cx
        pop bx
        pop ax 
        ret 
    
   
    ;;Imprimimos un string
    puts:
        push ax
        push bx
        push cx
        push dx  
        
        mov ah, 9h
        int 21h
        
        pop dx
        pop cx
        pop bx
        pop ax
        ret
    
    ;;Reproduce DING
    putBeep:
        mov dl, 07h
        call putC
        ret 
    
    ;;Liberamos recursos del procesador
    finish:
        mov ax, 4c00h  
        int 21h
        ret

end start
```

Comment: Presumably your input function forgot to chop off the carriage return from the end of the string, so when reversing, it will start with that and thus go back to the beginning of the line.

Comment: You need to debug it.  Single step and see where it first starts to go wrong.  Between instructions, look at your registers and your memory.  Make sure your pointer values in registers are pointing into your memory where they should and verify each memory read and write.  Get to know the layout of your data, the addresses of each item in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> call readText
>
> mov cx, si
> dec si
> ```

@Jester's hunch was correct! Whenever the user input ends with a carriage return, your *readText* routine returns with the carriage return byte included in the count in the SI register. Because the instructions that follow setup a counter with that value and move the offset to that particular carriage return byte, it will be a carrriage return that the *printArrayBackwards* code outputs first. This will move the cursor to the beginning of the line where you wrote the message "El texto al reves es: ". The characters that are output next, will start overwritting the message.

The simplest solution is probably to NOT include the terminator in the count that *readText* returns:

```
readText:
    xor  si, si             ; Make sure you start at the beginning of the array
PedimosCaracteres:
    call getc               ; -> AL
    cmp  al, 27
    je   esEsc
    cmp  al, 13
    je   esEnter
    mov  array[si], al
    inc  si                 ; Only counting 'true' characters
    jmp  PedimosCaracteres
esEsc: 
    mov  al, 0
esEnter:
    mov  array[si], al      ; Doesn't include the terminator {0,13} in the count
    ret
```